# How to fit an equation in python having three variables?

Tags: statistics, curves, mathematical-modeling, python

Equation to be fitted:
$p= my + nx$ where 
$$x=\frac{k}{1+e^{c-ut}}.$$
In the experimental data we have values of $p, y,$ and $t,$ 
so $13$ values for each of the three variables $p,y,$ and $t.$

Comment: What are $k, c, u, t?$ Are then known? Or are they parameters to be found? What is the complete list of parameters to find? Have you tried a preliminary look in Excel using the Solver?

Comment: m,n,k,c,u are the parameters to be found

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895369/how-to-run-non-linear-regression-in-python.

Comment: @AdrianKeister   checked that but in that one product is not used only scaling factor and baskets are used ...so basically two variables are used.

Comment: @Chris Mueller,@ mikuszefski will you also please check this question

Comment: I would just go with Excel and the Solver routine. You set up the differences of squares (assuming you want that for your error function), and Solver can find the best fit.